# Is the category of rational Lie algebras monoidal?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, monoidal-categories

I hate to ask such a naive question, but here goes. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are rational Lie algebras, i.e. rational vector spaces together with a bracket. Then, $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B$ is a rational vector space. Can it be endowed with a Lie bracket in such a way that the category of rational Lie algebras is a monoidal category? I came up with this question while reading Quillen's Rational Homotopy Theory and Schwede-Shipley's "Equivalences of Monoidal Model Categories", which mentions Quillen's work, but stops short of claiming any monoidal properties.

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be. But why the tensor product? If you want this to be related to rational homotopy theory then the relevant monoidal structure is just direct sum, isn't it? (And also you want gradings.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew Salch wrote me a nice email about this question, and with his permission, I'm turning it into an answer. Any mistakes are my own. I've made this answer CW, so I don't get any points for Andrew's work. The following is Andrew's email, lightly edited.

"The Milnor-Moore theorem tells you that, if $k$ is a field of characteristic zero, then the category of Lie algebras over $k$ is equivalent to the category of co-commutative primitively generated Hopf algebras over $k$: from Lie algebras to Hopf algebras, you have the universal enveloping algebra functor $U$, and from a Hopf algebra $A$ you can take its Lie algebra $PA$ of primitives, and if the ground field has characteristic zero, then $P$ and $U$ give you the Milnor-Moore equivalence of categories.

You have a nice extension theory in both settings: for Lie algebras it's very classical, and extension theory for Hopf algebras was developed in a series of papers by Bill Singer. The functor $U$ sends an extension of Lie algebras to an extension of Hopf algebras and the functor $P$ sends an extension (in Singer's sense) of co-commutative primitively generated Hopf algebras to an extension of Lie algebras. (Actually, I don't remember ever seeing that last fact in Singer's papers, but I think it's part of the motivation for what he was doing. I guess you better not take my word for it, and actually work out a proof if you're going to use this.)

Given two Lie algebras $g$ and $h$, you can form the trivial extension of $g$ by $h$, which is just the Cartesian product $g \times h$, like you'd expect. The trivial extension of the Hopf algebra $Ug$ by the Hopf algebra $Uh$ is just the tensor product $Ug \otimes_k Uh$.

So the ordinary Cartesian product gives you a monoidal structure on the category of Lie algebras over $k$, and on applying $U$ to translate all the Lie algebras into Hopf algebras, you get the tensor product (over $k$) of the Hopf algebras. This isn't so far from what you were asking about--it's not a tensor product of Lie algebras, but it's a monoidal product on Lie algebras that induces the tensor product on their universal enveloping algebras--so maybe it's useful."